# Jmeter ForEachController breaking out after HTTPRequest

Tags: foreach, jmeter

I've a forEachController which appears to be breaking out after the first run of a HTTP Request that happens within it.

The Controller looks like the following

[image]

The 'Navigate to Next FileId' HTTP Request executes fine with a Response 200 and Status ok. However while the first two debug samplers execute the final two don't happen. Any sampler that is put after the HTTPRequest doesn't occur and yet the test continues on with the next sampler after the ForEach FileId controller.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, this one has stumped me for a couple of days.

Here's the forEachController configuration.

[image]

Thanks,
Mark.

@UBIK_LOAD_PACK

Without the BeanShell Preprocessor and the HTTP Request (Navigate to Next fileId) is set to a request that is successfully performed earlier in the test and still the same result. First two debug samplers print out and the last two are ignored and the ForEachController exits. 
[image]

Comment: so how many variables in format `fields_N` do you have?

Comment: Can you make your jmx file available for download ? Or a simplified version of it ? What does your BeanshellPreProcessor do ?

Comment: Hi Kirill, the output of the debug sampler is

Comment: @Kirill S. 
Sorry just to prevent confusion the variable name is fileIds and the available variable from the debug Sampler is 

fileIds_matchNr=1

Comment: Hey UBIK LOAD PACK, I did as you suggested and made an entirely new test isolating the for loop and it worked perfectly which is more annoying because it gives no indication as to why it doesn't work for me. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for this behaviour unless you Beanshell Pre Processor does something particular like breaking the ForeachController loop condition by playing on fileIds variable value.

Comment: HI UBIK thanks for getting back to me. Please see the edit in the original comment with a pic of the ForEach Controller with the PreProcessor removed.